# Visual Studio 2017 - Specify an App Icon

Tags: icons, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to add my icon as the default application icon in my Visual Studio project.  The Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-an-application-icon-visual-basic-csharp) says to click on **Project** -> **Project Properties**, and then select the **Application** tab in the **Project Designer**.

When I click on **Project** -> **Project Properties**, what comes up is not the **Project Designer**, it's **(Project Name) Property Pages**.  As you can see in the photo below, there is nothing even remotely related to an "Application" tab.

[Image of Project Property Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsRgq.jpg)

How can I add my icon as the default app icon?

Comment: Are you sure you did not select the solution?

Comment: Thanks for your response, here is a GIF of me opening what should be the Project Designer. As far as I can tell I'm doing it correctly. https://gyazo.com/b88bdfbb97c8ecc8c6353414724cb2f6

Comment: What kind of project is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `.rc` file that is generated automatically when an icon is added to the resources of the project via [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb788183(v=vs.90).aspx) instructions.

There is actually a comment within this file that answers the question directly.

> // Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
>
> // remains consistent on all systems.

Following this comment are all the icons, and as expected, the one with the lowest ID becomes the application icon.

Note: Sometimes when running the executable within VS, the icon will not show up in the toolbar.

Comment: These instructions are obsolete, not valid anymore - at least for VS 2017

Comment: The instructions worked for me (Visual Studio 2019, on Dev 202.  It was correct that the app icon does not show up in the task bar in VS, but does show up if you rune the .exe directly.